# Can function parameter be set before it's invoked?

Tags: scala

Here I create a List of objects where each element is of type (String , () => Unit)

```
case class FunctionDesc(label: String, fun: () => Unit)
  def f() = {
    println("in f")
  }

  val functionList = List[FunctionDesc](FunctionDesc("a1", f), FunctionDesc("a2", f))

  functionList.foreach(f => f.fun())
```

This works fine but if I want to modify the function List to contain a parameter then have to decide what the parameter value
should be when the function is being implemented :

```
  case class FunctionDesc2(label: String, fun: (String) => Unit)
  def f2(str: String) = {
    println("in f2")
  }
  def f3(str: String) = {
    println("in f3")
  }
  val functionList2 = List[FunctionDesc2](FunctionDesc2("a3", f2), FunctionDesc2("a4", f3))
  functionList2.foreach(f => f.fun("param value"))
```

Can decide what the function parameter type should before it's invoked ?
So instead of

```
val functionList2 = List[FunctionDesc2](FunctionDesc2("a3", f2), FunctionDesc2("a4", f3))
```

use something like :

```
val functionList2 = List[FunctionDesc2](FunctionDesc2("a3", f2("f5")), FunctionDesc2("a4", f2("f6"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by making `f2` and `f3` return a function. Here's a simplified version:

```
case class FunctionDesc2(label: String, fun: (String) => Unit)

// `f` closes over `str` and returns a function from `String` to `Unit`
def f(str: String) = (s: String) => println(s"$str: $s")

val functionList = List(FunctionDesc2("a", f("foo")), FunctionDesc2("b", f("bar")))

functionList.foreach(_.fun("value"))
// foo: value
// bar: value
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use currying:

```
scala> case class FunctionDesc2(label: String, fun: () => Unit)
defined class FunctionDesc2

scala> def f2(str: String)(): Unit = {
     |   println("in f2")
     | }
f2: (str: String)()Unit

scala> def f3(str: String)(): Unit = {
     |   println("in f3")
     | }
f3: (str: String)()Unit

scala> val functionList2 = List[FunctionDesc2](FunctionDesc2("a3", f2("f5")), FunctionDesc2("a4", f3("f6")))
functionList2: List[FunctionDesc2] = List(FunctionDesc2(a3,<function0>), FunctionDesc2(a4,<function0>))

scala> functionList2.foreach(desc => desc.fun())
in f2
in f3
```